# envision / predict / forecast

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference, usage

If I have a quarrel with somebody and say:

- I can ***envision*** all your further words!

Is it appropriate in the context that I want to emphasise that all they words are a commonplace for me and they cannot persuade me to do something?

Or should I use a "predict", "forecast", etc.

Answer (score 1):

All of those are technically correct but are strangely phrased and would sound awkward.

More natural option in that situation would be to say something like

> I already know what you're going to say.

or

> I can predict what you're going to say

If somebody is making an argument and you want to tell them you're not convinced you might say

> I've heard it all before!

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Also, _envision_ means _see (in your mind's eye)_, so it suggests that you can 'see' the words written down!